# TypeError: result[0].data is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that should send notification when someone adds a comment.
But this error is shown in log.

```
TypeError: result[0].data is not a function
    at Promise.all.then.result (/srv/lib/index.js:19:35)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

And this is my function. What is wrong in here? How to change this?

```
/*eslint-disable */

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.apptTrigger = functions.firestore.document("Comments/{anydocument}").onCreate((snap, context) =>  {

    const receiver = snap.data().idUserImage;

    const messageis = snap.data().comment;


    const toUser = admin.firestore().collection("token").where('idUser', '==', receiver).get();


    return Promise.all([toUser]).then(result => {

      const tokenId = result[0].data().token;

    const notificationContent = {
           notification: {
              title: "Dodano komentarz",
              body: messageis,
              icon: "default",
              sound : "default"
            }};
               return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
                    tokenId,
                    notificationContent
                ).then(results => {
            console.log("Notification sent!");
            //admin.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(userEmail).collection("userNotifications").doc(notificationId).delete();
          });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal since the promise returned by the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method of a `Query` returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html) which "contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects representing the results of a query". Therefore there is no `data()` method for `result[0]`.

The QuerySnapshot documentation (link above) says:

> The documents can be accessed as an array via the **docs** property or
>   enumerated using the forEach method. The number of documents can be
>   determined via the empty and size properties.

Therefore you should use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property, which returns "an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`" and do as follows:

```
const tokenId = result[0].docs[0].data().token;
```

---

Note however that you don't need to use `Promise.all` in your case, since you are passing to it an array with only one element. You just have to use the `QuerySnapshot` returned by `get()` and use its `docs` property as follows:

```
exports.apptTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('Comments/{anydocument}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const receiver = snap.data().idUserImage;
    const messageis = snap.data().comment;

    const toUser = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('token')
      .where('idUser', '==', receiver)
      .get();

    return toUser
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const tokenId = querySnapshot.docs[0].data().token;

        const notificationContent = {
          notification: {
            title: 'Dodano komentarz',
            body: messageis,
            icon: 'default',
            sound: 'default'
          }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, notificationContent);
      })
      .then(results => {   //If you don't need the following console.log() just remove this then() 
        console.log('Notification sent!');
        return null;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Drop this error Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: Yes, there was an error in my answer, please see the update! Changed from `result.docs[0].data().token;` to `result[0].docs[0].data().token;`

Comment: See the second update, explaining that actually you don't need to use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that "result[0].data" is not function. However, you are accessing the "data" as function from your result[0] object.

```
 const tokenId = result[0].data().token;
```

You may have to change the above line of code to

```
const tokenId = result[0].data.token;
```

But before that I suggest to check if "data" itself is defined.

```
const tokenId;
if(result[0].data)
  tokenId = result[0].data.token;
```

Comment: Now give me this error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at Promise.all.then.result (/srv/lib/index.js:11:40)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)```

Comment: FYI, `const tokenId = result[0].data.token;` will not work, since `result[0]` is a `QuerySnapshot` which does not have a data property, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html